# Controlling measure zero sets of solutions with Manipulate.  A case study

Tags: math, wolfram-mathematica, geometry, visualization

To address the question we start with the following toy model problem being here just a case study:

*Given two circles on a plane (its centers (c1 and c2) and radii (r1 and r2)) as well as a positive number r3,  find all circles with radii = r3 (i.e all points c3 being centers of circles with radii = r3) tangent  (externally and internally) to given two circles.*

In general, depending on `Circle[c1,r1], Circle[c2,r2] and r3` there are 0,1,2,...8 possible solutions.  A typical case with 8 solutions :
[image]

I slightly modified a neat Mathematica implementation by Jaime Rangel-Mondragon on [Wolfram Demonstration Project](http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/ProblemsOnCirclesIVCirclesTangentToTwoOthersWithAGivenRadius/), but its core is similar:

```
Manipulate[{c1, a, c2, b} = pts;
           {r1, r2} = Map[Norm, {a - c1, b - c2}];

            w = Table[
                       Solve[{radius[{x, y} - c1]^2 == (r + k r1)^2, 
                              radius[{x, y} - c2]^2 == (r + l r2)^2}
                            ] // Quiet, 
                       {k, -1, 1, 2}, {l, -1, 1, 2}
                    ];
            w = Select[
                       Cases[Flatten[{{x, y}, r} /. w, 2],
                             {{_Real, _Real}, _Real}
                            ], 
                       Last[#] > 0 &
                     ];
           Graphics[
                    {{Opacity[0.35], EdgeForm[Thin], Gray,
                                                      Disk[c1, r1], Disk[c2, r2]},      
                     {EdgeForm[Thick], Darker[Blue,.5],
                                                   Circle[First[#], Last[#]]& /@ w}
                    },
                       PlotRange -> 8, ImageSize -> {915, 915}
                   ],
           "None" -> {{pts, {{-3, 0}, {1, 0}, {3, 0}, {7, 0}}},
                      {-8, -8}, {8, 8}, Locator}, 
           {{r, 0.3, "r3"}, 0, 8}, 
           TrackedSymbols -> True,
           Initialization :> (radius[z_] := Sqrt[z.z])
         ]
```

We can easily conclude that in a generic case we have an even number of solutions 0,2,4,6,8 while cases with an odd number of solutions 1,3,5,7 are exceptional - they are of zero measure in terms of control ranges. Thus changing in `Manipulate` `c1, r1, c2, r2, r3` one can observe that it is much more difficult to track cases with an odd number of circles.

One could modify on a basic level the above approach : solving purely symbolically equations for c3 as well as redesignig `Manipulate` structure with an emphasis on changing number of solutions.  If I'm not wrong `Solve` can work only numerically with `Locator` in `Manipulate`, however here `Locator` seems to be crucial for simplicity of controlling  `c1, r1, c2, r2` as well as for the whole implementation.
Let's state the questions,  :

**1.  How can we force Manipulate to track seamlessly cases with an odd number of solutions (circles) ?**

**2. Is there any way to make `Solve` to find exact solutions of the underlying equations?**

**( I find the answer by Daniel Lichtblau to be the best approach to the question 2, but it seems in this instance there is still an essential need for sketching of a general technique of emphasizing measure zero sets of solutions while working with Manipulate )**

**These considerations are of less importance while dealing with exact solutions**

*For example `Solve[x^2 - 3 == 0, x]` yields `{{x -> -Sqrt[3]}, {x -> Sqrt[3]}}`
while in case from the above of  slightly more difficult equations extracted from `Manipulate` setting the following arguments :*

```
 c1 = {-Sqrt[3], 0};  a = {1, 0};  c2 = {6 - Sqrt[3], 0};  b = {7, 0};     
 {r1, r2} = Map[ Norm, {a - c1, b - c2 }];  
  r = 2.0 - Sqrt[3];
```

*to :*

```
w = Table[Solve[{radius[{x, y} - {x1, y1}]^2 == (r + k r1)^2, 
                 radius[{x, y} - {x2, y2}]^2 == (r + l r2)^2}],
          {k, -1, 1, 2}, {l, -1, 1, 2}];

w = Select[ Cases[ Flatten[ {{x, y}, r} /. w, 2], {{_Real, _Real}, _Real}],    
            Last[#] > 0 &]
```

*we get two solutions :*

```
{{{1.26795, -3.38871*10^-8}, 0.267949}, {{1.26795, 3.38871*10^-8}, 0.267949}}
```

*similarly under the same arguments and equations, putting :*

```
r = 2 - Sqrt[3];
```

*we get no solutions :*  `{}`

*but in fact there is exactly one solution which we would like to emphasize:*

```
{ {3 -  Sqrt[3], 0 }, 2 -  Sqrt[3] }
```

In fact, passing to  `Graphics` such a small difference between two different  solutions and the uniqe one is indistinguishable, however working with `Manipulate` we cannot track carefully with a desired accuracy merging of two circles and usually the last observed configuration when lowering `r3` before vanishing all solutions (reminding so-called structural instability) looks like this :
[image]

`Manipulate` is rather a powerful tool, not only a toy, and its mastering could be very useful. The considered issues when appearing in a serious research are frequently critical, for example: in  studying solutions of nonlinear differential equations, occurence of singularities in its solutions, qualitative behavior of dynamical systems, bifurcations, phenomena in Catastrophe theory and so on.

Comment: There are two questions hidden right in the middle of this post. Could you maybe make them a little more obvious? (Also, maybe link to the original demonstration?)

Comment: It's not really the programming solution you're looking for, but the system of the two original circles is symmetric about the line joining their centers, so any solution with an odd number of circles will have one centered on that line. There are only four possible values of `r3` that allow for a circle to be centered on the line of symmetry, so you could check for those directly.

Comment: I did not intended to ask for finding cases with an odd number of solutions, which is not a serious difficulty, but rather to illustrate a general problem when working with `Manipulate` and `Solve` (and/or `DSolve`, `NDSolve` etc.) - how to control qualitative behavior of systems of (differential or polynomial etc) equations in order to not overlook crucial solutions.

Comment: Assuming you know the exceptional cases, you could use the Bookmarks option to get to some of them easily.

Comment: @Brett Champion thanks for a useful hint, but trying to figure out how I could apply that together with Daniel's comprehensive answer. The problem is that we have 7 degrees of freedom (2 radii and 4 centers of given circles, and the radius of sought circles) and we don't know in advance those exceptional cases.

Comment: I'm not sure if you're aware of this, but you can slow down the movement of the slider and locators in `Manipulate` by pressing Alt  while dragging the controls (or Alt+Ctrl for even finer control). Note that this works on OS X at least; for a different OS you might have to use different modifier keys. This would allow you to get a better approximation of the critical points.

Comment: @Heike  thanks, the same keys work also on Windows, I didn't know about them. It helps finely a bit, but the core of the problem remains.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As this is a measure zero set, tools that require some granularity will generally have trouble with the concept. Perhaps better is to look for the singularity locus explicitly, where solutions have multiplicity or in other ways depart from the nearby solution behavior(s). It will be a part of the discriminant variety. In particular, you can grab the relevant part by setting your defining polynomials to zero and simultaneously making the Jacobian determinant zero.

Here is your example. I will eventually (wlog) put one center at the origin and the other at (1,0).

```
centers = Array[c, {2, 2}];
radii = Array[r, 3];
circ[cen_, rad_, x_, y_] := ({x, y} - cen).({x, y} - cen) - rad^2
```

I'll use your 'k' for both polynomials. Your formulation has pairs (k,l) where each is +-1. We can just use k, arrange by squaring to get a polynomial in k^2, and replace that with 1.

```
 polys = 
 Table[Expand[
   circ[centers[[j]], radii[[3]] + k*radii[[j]], x, y]], {j, 2}]

Out[18]= {x^2 + y^2 - 2 x c[1, 1] + c[1, 1]^2 - 2 y c[1, 2] + 
  c[1, 2]^2 - k^2 r[1]^2 - 2 k r[1] r[3] - r[3]^2, 
 x^2 + y^2 - 2 x c[2, 1] + c[2, 1]^2 - 2 y c[2, 2] + c[2, 2]^2 - 
  k^2 r[2]^2 - 2 k r[2] r[3] - r[3]^2}
```

We'll remove the part that is linear in k, square the rest, square that removed part, and equate the two. We also then replace k with unity.

```
p2 = polys - k*Coefficient[polys, k];
polys2 = Expand[p2^2 - (k*Coefficient[polys, k])^2] /. k -> 1;
```

We now get the determinant of the Jacobian and add that to the brew.

```
discrim = Det[D[polys2, #] & /@ {x, y}];

allrelations = Join[polys2, {discrim}];
```

Now set the centers as noted earlier (could have done this from the beginning, one would suppose).

```
ar2 = 
 allrelations /. {c[1, 1] -> 0, c[1, 2] -> 0, c[2, 1] -> 0, 
   c[2, 2] -> 0}

Out[38]= {x^4 + 2 x^2 y^2 + y^4 - 2 x^2 r[1]^2 - 2 y^2 r[1]^2 + 
  r[1]^4 - 2 x^2 r[3]^2 - 2 y^2 r[3]^2 - 2 r[1]^2 r[3]^2 + r[3]^4, 
 x^4 + 2 x^2 y^2 + y^4 - 2 x^2 r[2]^2 - 2 y^2 r[2]^2 + r[2]^4 - 
  2 x^2 r[3]^2 - 2 y^2 r[3]^2 - 2 r[2]^2 r[3]^2 + r[3]^4, 0}
```

We now eliminate x and y to get the locus in r[1],r[2],r[3] parameter space that determines where we'll have multiplicity in our solutions.

```
 gb = GroebnerBasis[ar2, radii, {x, y}, 
   MonomialOrder -> EliminationOrder]

{r[1]^6 - 3 r[1]^4 r[2]^2 + 3 r[1]^2 r[2]^4 - r[2]^6 - 
   8 r[1]^4 r[3]^2 + 8 r[2]^4 r[3]^2 + 16 r[1]^2 r[3]^4 - 
   16 r[2]^2 r[3]^4}
```

If I did this all correctly, then we now have the polynomial defining the locus in parameter space where solution sets can get silly. Off this set they should never have multiplicity, and real counts should always be even. The intersection of this set with real space will be a 2d surface in the 3d space of the radii parameters. It will separate regions that have 0, 2, 4, 6, or 8 real solutions from one another.

Last, I'll point out that in this example the variety in question reduces nicely into a product of planes. I guess from a geometric view this is not too surprising.

```
Factor[gb[[1]]]

Out[43]= (r[1] - r[2]) (r[1] + r[2]) (r[1] - r[2] - 2 r[3]) (r[1] + 
   r[2] - 2 r[3]) (r[1] - r[2] + 2 r[3]) (r[1] + r[2] + 2 r[3])
```

Comment: I find your answer as one of the best I've ever seen on stackoverflow, however it seems to be a partial answer (although crucial), and my expectations targeted to couple a symbolic solution with a reasonable modifying Manipulate to emphasize measure zero cases.  Nevertheless I wonder why you've got only two points (including 1 from me)

Comment: @Artes Docendo I never know why answers get either few or many upvotes. As to your first question (tracking the exceptional cases), and your Manipulate, I have a question. What exactly is it that is problematic with the manipulation? It "looks" like it is behaving sensibly as it passes through an exception. What am i not seeing correctly?

Comment: @Artes Docendo Re having Manipulate notice measure zero sets, I will point out that discriminant varieties are hard enough to locate in the purely algebraic (system of polynomials) setting. Handling such sets in the full mathematical generality in which they tend to appear (or rather, disappear) is probably beyond the scope of what is currently achievable other than on a case-by-case basis. From a graphics point of view, it makes sense to handle them by ignoring them, that is, letting plots of objects with multiplicity just overlay one another.

Comment: Problematic with the manipulation is that in general we cannot stop controls exactly at the points (arguments, variables) of the exceptional cases.  While we can easily imagine we have the exceptional solutions to the problem at hand, so at this aspect everything is OK, and making `Manipulate` finely track such events like changing nuber of solutions is a kind of unnecessary luxury.  However in more sophisticated mathematical models (like systems of nonlinear ODE's)  I believe we could benefit of  `Manipulate` more, to prevent from  overlooking exceptional (being sometimes crucial) solutions.

Comment: Brett Champion pointed out of using the Bookmarks option, however I am not sure this could be really helpful.  When symbolic approach  yields  just an odd number of solutions (circles) could Bookmarks make controls in `Manipulate` stop exactly at the desired points?  There are rather no interesting examples of using that option in documentation.

Comment: One remark more:  I agree with your comment about discriminant varieties, nevertheless certain special techniques to achieve preview or perspective of different classes of solutions on a case-by-case basis would be very instructive.  I don't know, but I believe Michael Trott has tackled such problems when he has been working on updating his Mathematica GuideBooks, hasn't he ?  Be the way,  the newer edition (including the full scope of  `Manipulate`) would be very interesting right now.  Are you aware if those volumes come up  in the near future ?

Comment: @Artes Docendo Yes, ability to have a manipulation capture exceptional phenomena might be nice. In "good" cases it is an obvious event, as you visually notice either more or fewer paths, solutions, whatever when you cross a threshold. In bad cases the number does not change. But I've no idea how to get Manipulate to handle such things in general (let alone situations where we gain solutions only at critical points e.g. Sturm–Liouville). As for the Guide books, I do not know if they are being revised.

Comment: Thank You for the answers, they were all helpful,  although I am not aware more of neat examples and advanced techniques of dealing with Manipulate I believe there is still more to gain while working with it.