# Simple programming techniques / tricks in Mathematica for making graphics for the math book?

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I tried to use it. And it's really nice for some Plots, but when its about making for example a triangle I found it quite complicated. I figured out how to draw a triangle but how to add that angle marks, those curved lines?

And since I'm beginner into this job, of writing a book, can anyone recommend me which is the best way to accomplish good looking graphics, for example as in the picture below. Which programs are best to use. 
[image]

Thanks for any suggestions and recommendations.

Comment: Mathematica can definitely make all the graphics that you are showing as examples, but it won't help you make them very easily.  You'd need to define your own functions to make it easily to draw things like the angle-arcs.  Once this is done it should be easier.  I think Mathematica is really good if you need to make your drawings very precise, and you prefer to describe them using program code and equation. (Although it does have interactive editing.)  When interactive editing is better, I'd use something like http://zirkel.sourceforge.net/ (for the ones you're showing I'd use Z.u.L, not Mma)

Comment: To the closers: This is a perfectly legitimate programming question for the Mathematica tag, since things like graphics for math book are obtained programmatically in Mathematica.

Comment: For a general background, you might be interested in this presentation: http://www.wolfram.com/mathematica/customer-stories/developing-interactive-textbooks-with-cdf.html . It is much more than static images, but they are possible too, and perhaps even easier obtained at the end as "snapshots" of more dynamic ones.

Comment: @LeonidShifrin I have noticed that many legitimate Mathematica questions get close-voted.

Comment: @Tim Kemp This will hopefully end soon, since we have a new SE Mathematica site proposal getting momentum:http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/37304/mathematica . Please consider supporting it.

Comment: First of all thanks to Szabolcs on a really useful link. I'm a newbie to stackoverflow.com and I really like it. I think I didn't get still how things work here (e.g. I'm unfamiliar to close-voted), but I've seen the proposal and I like it, even I don't understand why it's not functional yet. Anyway thank you.

Comment: @Szabolcs approach should get you far.  `Offset` is your friend, as is the third argument of `Text`, etc...

Comment: @LeonidShifrin & Szabolcs After some thought I have committed; it really is too big an environment to live here and many questions are not strictly programming-related. Thank you for making us aware of the proposal.

Comment: @Tim Kemp Thanks for supporting the proposal. Having a dedicated SE site for Mathematica should be a really good thing.

Comment: @TimKemp I see you've just committed to the proposal, but your account is not linked to the one on [so] (says unregistered). Since you have more than 200 rep here, it counts more towards the commitment than an "unregistered user". I think all you need to do to is to click "register" on your account on [a51] and sign in with the _same_ openid you use for [so].

Comment: @yoda Have done so. Hope it helps.

Comment: I use Microsoft Visio for making many of my diagrams. Just google `visio stencil` to see examples. When I get better in M, may be I can write code to do them directly there, but for now, Visio would be much easier for me for making diagrams like the one you showed. http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=2497

Comment: @balboa, thank you for committing to the [proposal](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/37304/mathematica), but your Stack Overflow account is not linked to the [area51.se] account. Since you are quickly approaching 200 rep, it would be helpful if they were linked. We need 100 experienced users (200+ rep) to commit.

Comment: @rcollyer I did registration, I think it's what I should have done. Glad if I can help.

Comment: @balboa, yes, you're accounts are now linked. So, thanks.

Comment: I also wished there was a more comprehensive high level "compound primitives" library on Mathematica, but since even the graphics legends are clumsy, it doesn't seem to be a priority. Lets hope the needs for the MathModelica integration bring new capacities of this kind.

Comment: before joining to this forum community I posted similar question on Wolfram forum, I have got one also nice answer on making custom plots.. If someone is interested in same topic as I am, you can see the the nice example. Here's the link:

http://forums.wolfram.com/student-support/topics/27385

Answer (score 19):

Here is a simple/basic way to do the first one:

```
Graphics[{

 (* The dashed circle segment *)
 {
  Dashing[{.04, .01}], 
  Darker[Orange], 
  AbsoluteThickness[2], 
  Circle[{0, 0}, 1, {1, 2 \[Pi]}]
 },

 (* The solid circle segment *)
 {
  Orange, 
  AbsoluteThickness[2], 
  Circle[{0, 0}, 1, {0, 1}]
 },

 (* The radial lines and the small circle segment *)
 Line[{{0, 0}, {1, 0}}],
 Line[{{0, 0}, {Cos[1], Sin[1]}}],
 Circle[{0, 0}, .2, {0, 1}],

 (* Various text labels *)
 {
  Text[Style["\[Theta]", 24], .3 {Cos[.5], Sin[.5]}], 
  Text[Style["s", 24], 1.1 {Cos[.5], Sin[.5]}], 
  Text[Style["r", 24], {.5, -.1}]
 }
}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

The following is the exact same thing, but wrapped in `Manipulate` and parameterized
on the angle `alpha`:

```
Manipulate[
 Graphics[{
  {Dashing[{.04, .01}], Darker[Orange], AbsoluteThickness[2], 
  Circle[{0, 0}, 1, {\[Alpha], 2 \[Pi]}]},
  {Orange, AbsoluteThickness[2], Circle[{0, 0}, 1, {0, \[Alpha]}]},
  Line[{{0, 0}, {1, 0}}],
  Line[{{0, 0}, {Cos[\[Alpha]], Sin[\[Alpha]]}}],
  Circle[{0, 0}, .2, {0, \[Alpha]}],
  {Text[Style["\[Theta]", 
  24], .3 {Cos[\[Alpha]/2], Sin[\[Alpha]/2]}], 
  Text[Style["s", 24], 1.1 {Cos[\[Alpha]/2], Sin[\[Alpha]/2]}], 
  Text[Style["r", 24], {.5, -.1}]}
 }],
{{\[Alpha], 1}, 0, 2 \[Pi]}]
```

If you move the slider, the content will change accordingly:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: love it. thank you very much, just one question: How to learn to draw graphics like this? If you could give reference to tutorials, I mean how have you learned it? Thank you!

Comment: If you are going to create lots of these sorts of graphics, I would recommend reading the help page on Graphics (http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Graphics.html?q=Graphics&lang=en) and also the pages on Directives (http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/guide/GraphicsDirectives.html), which modify the graphics primitives.

Comment: Did you extend the image uploader palette to support animations?  I wanted to do this but didn't have time yet!  If you did this, could you mail it by any chance? :-)

Comment: @Szabolcs - No, I did not make any changes/additions to your (very useful) palette.

Answer (score 14):

**Edit** You can get inspiration from the Demonstrations project too.  [These are the triangle-related demonstrations.](http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/topic.html?topic=Triangles&limit=20)  After taking a quick look, I think you should see the geometry-related demonstrations by [Jay Warendorff](http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/author.html?author=Jay%20Warendorff).  He has made a lot of these, and they use a structured set of geometry-related functions that you most likely can reuse.

---

Here's an `angleArc` function to get you started.  This is just a small example of a helper function you could use, there's a lot of room for improvement.

```
angleArc[Polygon[vertices_List, ___], r_, i_] :=
 Module[{a, b, c, phi1, phi2},
  {a, b, c} = Take[RotateLeft[vertices, i-2], 3];
  {phi1, phi2} = Sort@N[{ArcTan @@ (a - b), ArcTan @@ (c - b)}];
  If[phi2 - phi1 > Pi, phi1 += 2 Pi];
  Circle[b, r, {phi2, phi1}]
 ]

poly = Polygon[{{0, 0}, {1, 2}, {2, 1}}];

Graphics[{EdgeForm[Thick], FaceForm[None], poly, 
  Table[angleArc[poly, .2, i], {i, Length[poly[[1]]]}]}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
Manipulate[
 With[{poly = Polygon[{a, b, c}]},
  Graphics[
   {EdgeForm[Thick], FaceForm[None], poly, 
    Table[angleArc[poly, .2, i], {i, Length[poly[[1]]]}]},
   PlotRange -> 2 {{-1, 1}, {-1, 1}}, Frame -> True
   ]
  ],
 {{a, {0, 0}}, Locator}, {{b, {1, 0}}, Locator}, {{c, {0, 1}}, Locator}
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Thank you, I'm really grateful for these examples.

Comment: @balboa Please see the link I just edited into the answer.  I would perhaps mail the author of those demonstrations and ask kindly for the latest version of his geometry functions.  The demonstration source code on its own is a great resource, if a little overwhelming for a beginner.

Comment: Thank you, once again. I'll do so. You have really helped.

Comment: I already gave you +1, but I'd do it again for the Demonstrations link. The Demonstrations Project is a fabulous resource, as deep as it is wide.

Comment: @balboa Consider this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8462244/controlling-measure-zero-sets-of-solutions-with-manipulate-a-case-study as a kind of inspiration while working on a math book, it is in the same direction as Szabolcs pointed out.

Comment: This question would be another hint for your quest: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8235778/cone-image-refinement

Answer (score 9):

One excellent, Wolfram-supported product is [Geometrica](http://www.wolfram.com/products/applications/geometrica/). It's not a cheap add-on at $495, but it will produce diagrams like yours far easier than doing them in raw <s>MMA</s> Mathematica. It's basically a very large extension of Szabolcs approach in the comments - a library of functions to draw stuff.

Comment: I'll check it also! thank you, can you just tell me what does MMA stand for?

Comment: @balboa Sorry, I got lazy: MatheMaticA.

Comment: thanks, and as I sad I'm a new to this world of MMA

Answer (score 8):

I like Mathematica a lot. But there are better options for geometric drawing.

Here you have a five minutes sketch done with [Geometry Expressions](http://www.geometryexpressions.com/) (very low resolution used):

[image]

Geometry Expressions does some nice planar geometry calculations and can export the results to Mma online.

Comment: I just tried this program it's easy to use. It has user friendly environment. Just if you are going to export graphics to EPS - don't, because it does not work. It looks awful, but BMP looks nice. btw do you know how to unhide object, after I hid it?

Comment: @balboa To hide/unhide use the "Toggle" under the view menu

Comment: @balboa And no, I never export to eps from GE

Comment: thanks for sharing this program with us

Comment: Another alternative I like a lot: Geogebra, http://www.geogebra.org/cms/ (it usually takes just a few seconds to make such plots, they can be annotated and exported very easily too).

Answer (score 5):

Yes, Mathematica's built-in graphics tools are a bit quirky in places, and there are some annoying omissions. But there's a good range of basic graphics, and, on the plus side, you're only a few keystrokes away from the mathematical tools you need to rectify some of the deficiencies of the graphics editor. Need an arc? Just calculate it below and copy/paste it in. Can't do that with Adobe Illustrator! There's broad access to equations and greek characters too. It could be helpful when there's nothing else to hand.

Here's the first one - it's not totally unacceptable ... :)

[image: mathematica built-in graphics]

Comment: "Just calculate it below and copy/paste it in"... I guess you forgot to include the code.

Comment: I didn't get it, in which program you did this(Mathematica?). It looks nice.
"Just calculate it below"-- can you be more specific, maybe to post a code of graphic? thanks for answer

Comment: This was done in Mathematica, using the drawing tools. Circle, line, set the width of the lines, choose a dashed style, pick a colour, and so on. As for the code, I typed in `Graphics[Circle[{0, 0}, 1, {0, Pi/3}]]` and pasted the arc into the graphic I was working on.

Comment: @cormullion hope you saw the comments on the above question, mentioning the [proposal for a Mathematica-specific StackExchange site](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/37304/mathematica). It would be great to see you commit and be involved in the beta site.

Answer (score 5):

Presentations is an excellent and low-cost ($50) graphics (and much more) package in MMA, written by David Park.
http://home.comcast.net/~djmpark/DrawGraphicsPage.html

It is mentioned as resource n.2 in our stackoverflow tool bag
[What is in your Mathematica tool bag?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4198961/what-is-in-your-mathematica-tool-bag)